# Varnish stops listening on port 80 after few hours

Tags: nginx, web-server, varnish, cache

I have configured varnish to listen on port 80 and nginx to listen on 8080.
After around 24 hours of uptime, my site has been down for 22 hours. I checked in and found varnish isn't listening on port 80.

When site is up:

```
abc@abc:~$ sudo netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      571/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      376/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9171            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      376/nginx        
tcp        0      0 publicip:6082           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      569/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      376/nginx         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6082                :::*                    LISTEN      569/varnishd
```

When site is down:

```
abc@abc:~$ sudo netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      376/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9171            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      376/nginx
tcp        0      0 publicip:6082           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      745/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      376/nginx
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6082                :::*                    LISTEN      745/varnishd
```

This is my /etc/default/varnish:

```
## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a 1GB
# fixed-size cache file.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,96m"
```

Is there a specific reason why varnish is not listening on port 80 in the second case? I can probably just check and if varnish is not up, restart it but that would still mean a few minutes of down time.

My varnish.vcl file: http://pastebin.com/UH2c8KdH
I'm on ubuntu 12.04 x86

It happened again after 2 hours or so and this is what I found from syslog.

```
Feb 14 18:16:00 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:16:51 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:17:49 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:18:06 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:19:33 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:21:25 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:22:34 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:28:28 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:29:41 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Feb 14 18:29:48 abc last message repeated 2 times
Feb 14 18:29:48 abc varnishd[745]: Child (749) died signal=3
Feb 14 18:29:49 abc varnishd[745]: Child cleanup complete
Feb 14 18:29:55 abc varnishd[745]: child (1380) Started
Feb 14 18:29:58 abc varnishd[745]: Pushing vcls failed: CLI communication error (hdr)
Feb 14 18:29:58 abc varnishd[745]: Stopping Child
Feb 14 18:29:58 abc varnishd[745]: Child (1380) said Child starts
Feb 14 18:29:59 abc varnishd[745]: Child (1380) said Child dies
Feb 14 18:30:02 abc varnishd[745]: Child (1380) died status=1
Feb 14 18:30:04 abc varnishd[745]: Child cleanup complete
```

I'm not sure why the process ids are different than the ones I posted earlier. Maybe I restarted it while troubleshooting. I can't really make out much from these logs. Any help is appreciated.

Adding more logs:

Details from `/etc/log/messages`:

First time it stopped:

```
Feb 13 17:40:44 dragon75 varnishd[581]: Child (583) died signal=3
Feb 13 17:41:09 dragon75 varnishd[581]: child (2682) Started
Feb 13 17:42:31 dragon75 varnishd[581]: Child (2682) said Child starts
Feb 13 17:51:48 dragon75 varnishd[581]: Child (2682) died status=1
Feb 13 17:51:48 dragon75 varnishd[581]: Child (-1) said Child dies
```

Second time it stopped:

```
Feb 14 18:29:48 dragon75 varnishd[745]: Child (749) died signal=3
Feb 14 18:29:55 dragon75 varnishd[745]: child (1380) Started
Feb 14 18:29:58 dragon75 varnishd[745]: Child (1380) said Child starts
Feb 14 18:29:59 dragon75 varnishd[745]: Child (1380) said Child dies
Feb 14 18:30:02 dragon75 varnishd[745]: Child (1380) died status=1
```

According to messages, at 16:31 varnish started and then there are 5 MARK messages in /var/log/messages and then the varnish child died message at 18:29. There is nothing in between.

I don't think resources are a bottleneck. This is a new website and still in testing phase. I haven't really put anything on it. There is no traffic except the uptime script that I have on another server which just checks for the homepage. This is the first time I'm using varnish.

Comment: Is there any relevant information in your logs ?

Comment: @lain how do I check the varnish logs? I don't remember if I set a log path anywhere in the configs. Can you tell me the default location of varnish logs.

Comment: try here ... /var/log/varnish.log

Comment: Yep ... I noticed it the second I wrote the comment ... that's why deleted it the moment ... but u were too fast :)

Comment: @GeekRide There is a directory /var/log/varnish but it's empty. By the way, I'm on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @GeekRide I added the logs. Please take a look.

Comment: @Iain I found some logs relevant to varnish in /var/log/syslog. I have added them to the question

Comment: More information is needed, does /var/log/messages have anything interesting? You also need to get stats from your system (load avgs, traffic, memory etc) to check if there are bottlenecks/bugs somewhere and additionally make sure that your backend server is doing well. Right now as far as we know nginx could cause this problem, or your system runs out of memory etc etc

Comment: @jijix I added the contents from /var/log/messages. There are logs of varnish child dieing. I have posted them now. There is almost no traffic. I had rebuild the system and haven't put anything on the site. Only installed nginx, php5-fpm, wordpress and varnish. RAM is 512 MB, 2 cores, avg load shows 0.0 0.0 0.0 in htop since, I restarted it, its been like 2 hours. I'm pretty sure there is nothing going on the system. It's mostly idle.

Comment: Since this is the first time you are using varnish and it appears that you are new to all this, start with the basics: first run your website as simply as possible (i.e. without any caching servers/accelerators etc), make sure this runs smoothly and then move on to trying new stuff.

Comment: @jijix Do you mean testing the server with just the nginx + wp? I haven't made any changes to the nginx config. It's the same that I use with other websites and they work fine. I only changed the port it listens on to localhost and 8080 while varnish on 80. I really have no idea what is going wrong. By the way, I have 2 cores but I use 4 worker processes in nginx, could that be the cause?

Comment: Sometimes the "Child (749) not responding to CLI, killing it" happens when the backend stops responding. Another thing I find odd (though maybe irrelevant) is that nginx listens to :::80 (ipv6)  but varnish listens to 0.0.0.0:80, there might be something misconfigured there

Comment: @jijix I don't have ipv6, so I thought it wouldn't matter and didn't change those.

Comment: I'll suggest you to add some kind of daemon watcher software like monit (http://mmonit.com/monit/) to take care of this kind of issues

Answer (score 1):

Increase the cli_timeout parameter in Varnish to 60s.

This controls how long the monitoring parent will wait for the child to respond to a health check. If the operating system is busy paging data to/from disk, the 10s default may be to low. Increase it to one minute (default from 4.0 on) and see if the problem goes away.

If that doesn't help, my next guess would be over-eager log rotation scripts that kills more than they should.